# report lab function doesn't generate pdf file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf-generation, reportlab

I'm trying to draw strings on a jpg image and make it pdf with reportlab.
When i'm doing it like this it works:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import landscape, A4, letter
from reportlab.lib.units import cm, inch


file = 'test.pdf'
name = 'Nita Alexandru Stefan'
year = '1993'

c = canvas.Canvas(file, pagesize=landscape(letter))
c.drawImage('cert.jpg', 0*cm, 0*cm, 29*cm, 22*cm)
c.setFont("Times-Roman", 12)
c.setFillColorRGB(0.2578125, 0.2265625, 0.23046875)
c.drawString(500, 374, name)
c.drawString(429, 359, year)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

I want to make a function and use dict.get(), when i'm trying this it doesn't generate anything:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import landscape, A4, letter
from reportlab.lib.units import cm, inch

data = dict(name='Nita Alexandru Stefan', year='1993')


def generate_pdf(data, canvas):
    file = 'test.pdf'
    c = canvas.Canvas(file, pagesize=landscape(letter))
    c.drawImage('cert.jpg', 0*cm, 0*cm, 29*cm, 22*cm)
    c.setFont("Times-Roman", 12)
    c.setFillColorRGB(0.2578125, 0.2265625, 0.23046875)
    c.drawString(500, 374, data.get('name', ""))
    c.drawString(429, 359, data.get('year', ""))
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
```

Any ideea why it's not generating anything, nor changing the file created before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not calling the `generate_pdf function`

Call :

```
generate_pdf(data, canvas)
```

after the function `generate_pdf` ends

like:

```
def generate_pdf(data, canvas):
    file = 'test.pdf'
    c = canvas.Canvas(file, pagesize=landscape(letter))
    c.drawImage('cert.jpg', 0*cm, 0*cm, 29*cm, 22*cm)
    c.setFont("Times-Roman", 12)
    c.setFillColorRGB(0.2578125, 0.2265625, 0.23046875)
    c.drawString(500, 374, data.get('name', ""))
    c.drawString(429, 359, data.get('year', ""))
    c.showPage()
    c.save()

generate_pdf(data, canvas)
```

Comment: ok, i understand that, how can i call the function to get the wanted result?